# MySqlDataReader giving error at build

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, .net-4.0

I have a function in VB.NET that authenticates a user towards a MySQL database before launching the main application. Here's the code of the function:

```
    Public Function authConnect() As Boolean
    Dim dbserver As String
    Dim dbuser As String
    Dim dbpass As String
    dbserver = My.Settings.dbserver.ToString
    dbuser = My.Settings.dbuser.ToString
    dbpass = My.Settings.dbpass.ToString
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    myConnString = "server=" & dbserver & ";" & "user id=" & dbuser & ";" & "password=" & dbpass & ";" & "database=rtadmin"
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myData As New DataTable
    Dim myDataReader As New MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String

    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Username", login_usr_txt.Text))
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?Password", login_pass_txt.Text))
    query = "select * from users where user = ?Username and passwd = ?Password"
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnString
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Try
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            myCommand.CommandText = query
            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
            myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            If myDataReader.HasRows() Then
                MessageBox.Show("You've been logged in.", "RT Live! Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Function
```

The function is not yet complete, there are a few other things that need to be done before launching the application, since I'm using a MessageBox to display the result of the login attempt.

The error that I'm getting is the following:

> Error 1 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Friend Sub New(cmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand, statement As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement, behavior As System.Data.CommandBehavior)' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. C:\Users\Mario\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Remote Techs Live!\Remote Techs Live!\Login.vb 43 13 Remote Techs Live!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to try to create a MySqlDataReader and then throw it away!

First you do this to attempt to create a reader:

```
    Dim myDataReader As New MySqlDataReader
```

Then later you attempt to throw that away when you do this:

```
    myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
```

Just remove the New from your initial declaration.  I suspect that the constructor for the MySqlDataReader is not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the .AddWithValue instead of .Add.

For example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Username", login_usr_txt.Text)
```

Comment: Actually, that is correct as it is for what I can tell. The error comes from this line:

Dim myDataReader As New MySqlDataReader

where myDataReader is marked in blue and generates the mentioned error.